# Apply Socket.io in social network

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am building a social network application like facebook twitter. In this application one user have many followers. I need to apply socket.io when I give a status then It's only published on group of followers those who follow this specific user only. I've implemented socket.io in my application but now It's working all of the browser newsfeed but I want to apply socket only those who follow me.

I applied socket following way,
***At client,***

```
   socket.emit('load-post', timelinePost);
    socket.on('post-received', function(timelinePosts) {
      $rootScope.timelinePosts = timelinePosts;
    });
```

***Server,***

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('new connection made!');
        // Broadcast the post
        socket.on('load-post', function(data) {
            socket.emit('post-received', data);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('disconnected!');
        });
    });
```

News feed functions where I want to apply socket,

```
getNewsFeedServices.getStatusPosts().then(function(successMessage) {
      $rootScope.posts = successMessage.data;
    }, function(errorMessage) {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    });
```

This function load all the news feed informations of user followers and bring out all followers posts and then It's load individual accounts holder. But I want to apply here socket when user post a status then only followers get this status. How can I do this, any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

consider creating a [Room](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) for every online person, and then join the new and old active sockets (owned by followers) to that room.

Comment: If I manage room for group of users then how can I update status for individual user account. Suppose for 10 users I assigned room1 in backend then in client side how to detect this 10 users and update the status for those. I just confused how can I apply room or namespace  here.

Comment: IF P Q & R  following Mr X,  then when X comes online create  room callex roomX. and join P and Q, then when R comes online create roomR. and also joing R to roomX.   now from server any time you can say emit to roomX. and it will reach P Q R

Comment: I populate my following user using mongoose query. Just I pass my user Id to server then its load all of my following user. In this case how to detect those following user individually apply socket in those user browser.